# Is possible to get the status of notification from Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We made a java server app to send push notification to mobile devices throught Azure Notification Hub. We need to know the delivery status, is it possible? is there an api on Azure to grab the notification status, delivery info (date, time, ...) or failure status?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Standard tier notification hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/), then you use the the following api:

[Per Message Telemetry: Get Notification Message Telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt608135(v%3Dazure.100))

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I need, tnx